# What are the most common mistakes when pronouncing Pinyin?

Tags: pinyin

For example, 'shuo' is sometimes mistakenly pronounced 'shou'. 'Juan' is often pronounced 'zhuan'.

Can anyone think of any others? I want to highlight some common mistakes to teach pinyin pronunciation.

Comment: Are you asking for a list of "common" mistakes? Apart from the fact that list questions are not the kind of questions we actually want (especially open-ended lists), how do we know which mistakes are the most common? We'd need to agree on some standard resource, or some method to choose them.

Comment: This question is too subjective unless a proper source is provided. Personally I don't mistakenly pronounce "shuo" but often confuse "cu" and "shu", but that's just me, and it's irrelevant to a Q&A website.

Comment: This question has been closed as too subjective. This is more based on personal experiences.

Comment: Juan is often confused with zhuan.  Pinyin words which begin with j, x, q follow different rules that most other words.  Just wondered if there were any others which were common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people from south China, the following may be confused:

- z / zh
- c / ch
- s / sh
- n / l
- l / r

Many Pinyin input methods include "fuzzy pronunciations", a feature that automatically matches these confusable pronunciations. For example, if you input `zui`, the results will also include all characters of `zhui`.

The Google Pinyin input method uses the following list:

- z / zh
- c / ch
- s / sh
- an / ang
- en / eng
- in / ing
- l / n
- f / h
- r / l
- k / g
- ian / iang
- uan / uang

Comment: Well google obviously knows some of the mistakes.  Useful, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

ng=> mg

zh=> ch

ch=> zh

?n=> ?ng

zhu??=>qu??